# Graphical obviousification of the quadratic formula

Tags: geometry, quadratics, conic-sections

So there is a million (essentially equivalent) ways to make it obvious **algebraically** that the axis of symmetry of the parabola $y=x^2+bx+c$, must be at $x=-\frac{b}{2}$, while its real roots, if they exist, are $\pm\sqrt{\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)^2-c}$ away from that axis.

It feels like there must be a way to make this graphically obvious as well: The line $y=bx+c$ is tangent to the parabola at $x=0$, so the graphical interpretation of $b$ and $c$ are as the slope or $y$-intercept, respectively, of the parabola at $x=0$.

The question: Given these (or some other less obvious) graphical interpretations of $b$ & $c$, and without doing the standard algebra (completing the square etc.), is there a way to "read off" from the parabola graph that $\sqrt{\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)^2-c}$ must be the distance between a root and the symmetry axis? (Intuitely, a Pythagoras-like argument, based on some geometric definition of parabola?)

What I am looking for is an argument like the following, which makes it visually obvious that $(a+b)^2=a^2+2ab+b^2$:

[image]

Comment: I posted an answer but it did not have any pictures so was down-voted. In short: try defining the distance between the x-intercepts as d and then find an expression for d in terms of a,b,c. I think it is possible.

Comment: Thanks, but this seems essentially algebraic to me and thus a variant of the many standard algebraic ways...

Comment: Thanks. Indeed it is essentially the same question, but the answers do not seem to answer it. An object of the form $x^2+bx+c$ is basically a shifted $x^2$, so I do not yet see where the complexity comes from, and why there does not exist a high-school-math picture-like argument that does the trick.

Comment: Lill’s method (esp. The Thales version on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lill%27s_method) is visual, but involves slopes, and doesn’t quite fit the bill.